# Monte Carlo style to evaluate an integral MATLAB

Tags: matlab, montecarlo, approximation

I knew that we could approximate **pi** using Monte Carlo method by "throwing" point on the top right corner and count how many of them are inside the circle etc..

I want to do that for **every function f**, so I am "throwing" **random points** in the rectangle **[a,b] x [0;max(f)]** and I'm testing if my random_point_y is lower than f(random_point_x) and then I divide the total amount by the number of point below f.
Here is the code :

```
clear
close all
%Let's define our function f
clear
close all
f = @(x) exp(-x.^2);
a=-1; b=1;
range = [a:0.01:b];
f_range = f(range);

%Let's find the maximum value of f
max_value = f(1);
max_x = range(1);
for i = range
    if (f(i) > max_value) %If we have a new maximum
        max_value = f(i);
        max_x = i;
    end
end


n=5000;
count=0;
%Let's generate uniformly distributed points over [a,b] x [0;max_f]
x = (b-a)*rand(1,n) + a;
y = rand(1,n) * max_value;

for i=1:n
    if y(i)<f(x(i)) %If my point is below the function
        count = count + 1;
    end
end


%PLOT
hold on

%scatter(x,y,'.')
plot(range,f_range,'LineWidth',2)
axis([a-1 b+1 -1 max_value+1])
integral = (n/count)

hold off
```

for example I had for f = e^(-x^2) between -1 and 1 : [image: monte carlo]

But I have for result **1.3414**,**1.3373** for 500.000 points.
The exact result is **1.49365**

What am I missing ?

Comment: btw you could do:     `a=-1;` `b=1;`
    `f = @(x) exp(-x.^2);`
    `n=5000;`
    `randnums=a+(b-a)*rand(1,n);`
    `intg=(b-a)*mean(f(randnums))`

Comment: Yes it works but I really want to implement that "firing".
And also if I set `f = @(x) exp(-x.^2);` and the test as `if x(i)^2+y(i)^2 <= 1` it get the same error so I really don't know from where it comes from..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two small mistakes:

- It should be `count/n`, not `n/count`. Using the correct `count/n` will give the *proportion* of points below the curve.
- To get the *area* below the curve, multiply that proportion by the area of the rectangle, `(b-a)*max_value`.

So, use `count/n * (b-a)*max_value`.

---

Apart from this, your code would be faster and clearer with some vectorization:

```
clear
close all
f = @(x) exp(-x.^2);
a=-1; b=1;
range = [a:0.01:b];

%Let's find the maximum value of f
max_value = max(f(range));

n=50000;
%Let's generate uniformly distributed points over [a,b] x [0;max_f]
x = (b-a)*rand(1,n) + a;
y = rand(1,n) * max_value;

count = sum(y < f(x));
result = count/n * (b-a)*max_value
```

Comment: @RomainB. Well, it replaces the `count = count + 1` in your loop. The comparison `y < f(x)` with equal-size vectors gives a vector whose entries equal `true` (`1`) or `false`(`0`), and `sum` just computes the sum